# Can't get my .Net Console App to run on a Server "The Publisher Could Not Be Verified"

Tags: c#, ssis, console, code-signing

I've written a simple C# console app that gets executed by SQL Server Integration Services  as part of a datawarehouse load (on Windows Server 2003).

Unfortunately the step that calls the .exe is failing because a Open File security warning dialog "The Publisher Could Not Be Verified. Are you sure you want to run this software" is shown.

I think I need to sign my console app, but this seems a little overkill for an internal application. Can I sign it without having to get an externally recognised certificate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, signing is easy, Just look up Project|Options|Signing. The combobox will let you pick a key-file or create one. It is always a good idea.

But signing may not be enough, the server may impose stricter rules so that you will need a certificate.  I'm not 100% sure but you may be abkle to create your own and tell the server to trust it.

But try the signing first.